# Spines of Teichmuller space of a non-orientable surface

Tags: gr.group-theory, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Let $S_{g,n}$ be the orientable surface of genus $g$ and $n$ punctures. Denote $\Gamma_{g,n}$ be the mapping class group of $S_{g,n}$ and $\mathcal T_{g,n}$ the Teichmüller space of $S_{g,n}$.

In [http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lji/a-tale-of-two-groups.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Elji/a-tale-of-two-groups.pdf) page 34 item (17) it is mentioned that, provided $n>0$, $\mathcal T_{g,n}$ has a $\Gamma_{g,n}$-equivariant spine of dimension equal to the virtual cohomological dimension of $\Gamma_{g,n}$.

Is there an analogous result for a non-orientable surface with at least one puncture? That is, is it true that the Teichmüller space of a non-orientable surface with at least one puncture has a spine of dimension equal to the virtual cohomological dimension of the corresponding mapping class group?

Answer (score 1):

Yes... I think so?  See Theorem 6.9 of Ivanov's paper [Complexes of curves and the Teichmüller modular group](https://www.turpion.org/php/paper.phtml?journal_id=rm&paper_id=1440) (paywalled).  It looks like his computation of the vcd goes via a (deformation?) retraction to the desired spine.

By the way, I found this via Ivanov's article in Farb's book [Problems on the mapping class group and related topics](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Efarb/papers/mcgbook).  See Chapter 4, Section 10.

Comment: I do not know. I have been reading Ivanov's paper and I am not able to see where does he constructs such a spine.